# Running postgresql and hasrua throws an error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, hasura

I have a problem. I want to run a `postgresql` with `hasura`. I want to get inside the `postgresql` with Pgadmin. Therefore I would like top open the ports. Unfourntaly I got an error, please see below.

```
hasura_101-postgres-1 | 2022-07-14 09:46:31.515 UTC [680] DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
```

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.8.4
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      ## postgres database to store Hasura metadata
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## this env var can be used to add the above postgres database to Hasura as a data source. this can be removed/updated based on your needs
      PG_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/postgres
      ## enable the console served by server
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # set to "false" to disable console
      ## enable debugging mode. It is recommended to disable this in production
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      ## uncomment next line to set an admin secret
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: myadminsecretkey
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/running-postgresql-and-hasrua-throws-an-error/126675

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your docker-compose.yml file and tried running it and it works just fine. I don't see any issues in your configuration here.

Did you perhaps try modifying environment variables after you had already spun up the services once? If you change the password after the Postgres instance has already been created it won't actually take affect because of the volume mount.

Try just dropping your volumes and then recreating the stack and I suspect it will work just fine for you:

`docker-compose down -v` (-v means remove volumes)

then

`docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @Pyyyyt did this help to solve your issue?